# How to make a private npm repo executable with npx?

Tags: npx

I'm working on a command-line library, `@namespace/cli`.

When I'm in my local project directory, I can run `npx .` and the cli starts as expected.

However, after I `npm publish` and then run `npx @namespace/cli`, I get the error "cli is not a command".

What's the correct way to structure this project so it can be invoked using `npx`?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not :/

Comment: Any updates on this?